# Template Resolution in <Inside The C++ Object Model>

Tags: c++, templates, resolution

In Chapter 7 of "Inside the C++ Object Model," it was written that the resolution of a nomember name depends on whether the use of name is related to "the type of parameter used to instantiate the template."
I write a test:

```
/// -------------Test.h---------------
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern double foo(double t);

template <typename T>
class Test {
    public:
        void fun1() {
            member = foo(val);
        }
        T fun2() {
            return foo(member);
        }
    private:
        int val;
        T member;
};

#endif
```

and

```
/// -------------test1.cc-------------
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double foo(double t) {
    cout << "foo doule is called" << endl;
    return t;
}

int foo(int t) {
    cout << "foo int is called" << endl;
    return t;
}
-------------test.cc--------------
#include "Test.h"

extern int foo(int t);

int main() {
    Test<int> fi;
    fi.fun1();
    fi.fun2();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect  "foo double is called\n
           foo int is called", 
but I got "foo double is called\n
           foo double is called".
My g++ version is bellow. I'll be appreciate it if you can help me.

[image: My g++ version]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the book is not painting the complete picture (and it's a bit aged). Yes, `foo(member)` is a function call that is dependent on the template parameter. But the specific way in which functions are looked up in templates is described in the C++ standard at [[temp.dep.candidate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate):

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name,
>   the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either
>     the template definition context or the template instantiation context
>     are found.

`foo`'s overloads can be looked up in one of two ways. By direct unqualified lookup, and by [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (aka ADL). Simple unqualified lookup considers only the names that are known at the point of the template definition. Since you only declared `foo(double)`, that is the only overload found at the point of the template definition.

At the point of instantiation, the compiler *will* try to do ADL to find more `foo`'s, but fundamental types don't contribute to ADL. `int` cannot be used to find `foo(int)`. So the compiler can do only one thing, convert the integer to a double, and call `foo(double)`.

If you want to test your compilers ADL, you just need to add a simple user defined type and overload. For instance:

```
enum E{};
E foo(E) {
  cout << "foo E is called\n";
  return {};
}

int main() {
    Test<E> fi;
    fi.fun1();
    fi.fun2(); 
    return 0;
}
```